# How can i create sublist inside a xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml but i dont know how can i write this. Because this xml has got sub list inside. I dont know how can I write it? can you help me about this point ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>
<SALES_INVOICES>
  <INVOICE DBOP="INS" >
    <TYPE>9</TYPE>        
    <TRANSACTIONS>
      <TRANSACTION>
        <TYPE>4</TYPE>           
      </TRANSACTION>
      <TRANSACTION>
        <TYPE>4</TYPE>          
      </TRANSACTION>         
    </TRANSACTIONS>
    <PAYMENT_LIST>
      <PAYMENT>
        <DATE>01.01.2013</DATE>           
       </PAYMENT>
    </PAYMENT_LIST>
    <AFFECT_RISK>0</AFFECT_RISK>
    <DOC_DATE>19.03.2013</DOC_DATE>
    <GUID></GUID>
    <EDURATION_TYPE>0</EDURATION_TYPE>
    <EDTCURR_GLOBAL_CODE>TL</EDTCURR_GLOBAL_CODE>
  </INVOICE>
</SALES_INVOICES>
```

I write code;

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\1.xml"))
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartDocument();
                        writer.WriteStartElement("SALES_INVOICES");
                        writer.WriteStartElement("INVOICE");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("DBOP", "INS");
                        writer.WriteStartElement("Trancastions");


                        foreach (var transaction in orderTransactionDto)
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement("Trancastion");
                            writer.WriteElementString("ID", transaction.Id.ToString());   
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                        }

                        writer.WriteEndElement();                        
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        writer.WriteEndDocument();
                    }
```

How can I write this linq to xml ?

Best Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by `this xml has got sub list inside. I dont know how can I write it?`. Can you clarify your question please?

Comment: Hi. you can see transactions node. this node has got 2 transaction child node inside. i dont know how can i write this transactions node

Comment: You need to study how to write xml files using xml writter then. here is a link http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not so hard ,try this:

```
var TRANSACTIONS=new XElement("TRANSACTIONS");
TRANSACTIONS.Add(new XElement("TRANSACTION",new XElement("TYPE",4)));
TRANSACTIONS.Add(new XElement("TRANSACTION",new XElement("TYPE",5)));
TRANSACTIONS.Add(new XElement("TRANSACTION",new XElement("TYPE",6)));
```

Comment: how can i add one of more Transaction under the transactions node. how can i foor look your code ?TRANSACTIONS.Add(new XElement("TRANSACTION",new XElement("TYPE",4)));

Comment: can u see my first post update ? i write code but how can i write this code linq-xml ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to select the `TRANSACTIONS` node from the XML. Create the child `TRANSACTION` node and set the child `TYPE` value. You can do this with [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
//Load the doc
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("your xml file..."));

//Get the transactions node
var transactionsNode = xml.Descendants().Elements("TRANSACTIONS").SingleOrDefault();

//Create a child transaction node
XElement elem = new XElement("TRANSACTION");

//Create a child type node and set its value to 200
elem.SetElementValue("TYPE", 200);

//Append this to the parent transactions node
transactionsNode.Add(elem);

//Save the XML back to file
xml.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("your xml file...");
```